# Unable to set image view background image using universal image loader?

Tags: android, lazy-loading, universal-image-loader

I am trying to set background for the image view. But not got luck to set background using universal image loader.

I am using following code.

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                                    .showStubImage(R.drawable.mo_no_image)
                                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.mo_no_image)
                                    .cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc()
                                    .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(0))
                                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY).build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("url_to_load_image", imgView, options);
```

By using above code I am able to set image resource which check aspect ratio and using that modifying image size.
        I want to set downloaded image to the background of image view.

Comment: You can use `loadImage()` method with listener and set background in `onaLoadingComplete()` callback. You have incoming Bitmap  in this callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend a different way that works like a charm: Android Query.

You can download that jar file from http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list

```
AQuery androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);
```

As an example:

```
androidAQuery.id(YOUR IMAGEVIEW).image(YOUR IMAGE TO LOAD, true, true, getDeviceWidth(), ANY DEFAULT IMAGE YOU WANT TO SHOW);
```

It's very fast and accurate, and using this you can find many more features like Animation when loading; getting a bitmap, if needed; etc.

In your case you need to fetch Bitmap, so for it, use below code

```
androidAQuery.ajax(YOUR IMAGE URL,Bitmap.class,0,new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>(){
                        @Override
                        public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
                            super.callback(url, object, status);

                            //You will get Bitmap from object.
                        }

});
```

Use this bitmap to set your background resource of ImageView using method.

Comment: Thank you. Is is possible using universal image loader? I have used that library in the entire project. And changed the lib could cause may issues.

Comment: Universal image loader is not a perfect solution. Android Query was provided by Android, so I think its best for everything. And Android Query can do many kind of things, its not only for Images, search about it and you will definitely get benefit through it.

Comment: please upvote the answer if you found it suitable, so others can get benefit of this.

Answer (score 1):

Universal Image Loader also provide to use the Background functionality.Please check the below coed for it:-

Here Uri is the path of the folder image OR the url of the image.

```
imageLoader.loadImage(YOUR_URL, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
   super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
   layout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(loadedImage));
  }
});
```