# How To Set in Background Of Image View

Tags: android

i am New On Android I want set image in Background Which is getting from Url ..I am using ImageLoader Class 
please Help me Set Image view In Background..

This Is MY Image Loader Class

```
public class ImageLoader {

// the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with
// something like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

private File cacheDir;

static ArrayList<String> img_path = new ArrayList<String>();

static String sd_card_folder_name = "ImageLoader";

static int width;

public ImageLoader(Context context, Activity acc) {
    // Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect
    // the UI performance
    photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    acc.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    Log.d("width", "width = " + width);

    cache.clear();

    img_path = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(), sd_card_folder_name);
    else
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();

}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.loader;

public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) {
    try {
        String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());

        File[] file_array = cacheDir.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < file_array.length; i++) {
            img_path.add(file_array[i].getName());
        }

        if (img_path.contains(filename)) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/" + sd_card_folder_name + "/"
                            + filename));
        } else {
            if (cache.containsKey(url)) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
            } else {
                queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView, filename);
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView, String _name) {
    // This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be
    // some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them.
    photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView, _name);
    synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
        photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
        photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
    }

    // start thread if it's not started yet
    if (photoLoaderThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
        photoLoaderThread.start();
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    // I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the
    // demo.

    if (url != null && !(url.equals(""))) {
        String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);

        /*
         * // from SD cache Bitmap b = decodeFile(f); if (b != null) return
         * b;
         */
        // from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
         final int REQUIRED_SIZE=300;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }
        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

// Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public String _name;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i, String n) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
        _name = n;
    }
}

PhotosQueue photosQueue = new PhotosQueue();

public void stopThread() {
    photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
}

// stores list of photos to download
class PhotosQueue {
    private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad = new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

    // removes all instances of this ImageView
    public void Clean(ImageView image) {
        for (int j = 0; j < photosToLoad.size();) {
            if (photosToLoad.get(j).imageView == image)
                photosToLoad.remove(j);
            else
                ++j;
        }
    }
}

class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                // thread waits until there are any images to load in the
                // queue
                if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() == 0)
                    synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                        photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                    }
                if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() != 0) {
                    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                    synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                        photoToLoad = photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                    }
                    Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                    cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                    Object tag = photoToLoad.imageView.getTag();
                    String FileName = photoToLoad._name;
                    if (FileName != null
                            && ((String) FileName).equals(photoToLoad._name)) {
                        BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp,
                                photoToLoad.imageView, FileName);
                        Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView
                                .getContext();
                        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                    }
                }
                if (Thread.interrupted())
                    break;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // allow thread to exit
        }
    }
}

PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread = new PhotosLoader();

// Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView imageView;
    String file_name;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i, String _name) {
        bitmap = b;
        imageView = i;
        file_name = _name;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (bitmap != null) {

            load_full_image(imageView, file_name, bitmap);

        } else
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private Runnable mMyRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
};

public void load_full_image(ImageView img, String _name, Bitmap btmp) {
    img_path = new ArrayList<String>();

    File[] file_array = cacheDir.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < file_array.length; i++) {
        img_path.add(file_array[i].getName());
    }

    if (img_path.contains(_name)) {
        img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                .decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/" + sd_card_folder_name + "/"
                        + _name));
    } else {
        img.setImageBitmap(btmp);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    // clear memory cache
    cache.clear();

    // clear SD cache
    File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
    for (File f : files)
        f.delete();
}
```

this is my Activity Where I Get Image In imagview

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.userprofile);
Button addfrnd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addfrnd);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
UserModel user = (UserModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("User");
 UserByIdModel tempuser = (UserByIdModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("UserById");
String UserId=String.valueOf(tempuser.getUser_Id());
String image_url=tempuser.getUser_Image();
int loader = R.drawable.loader;
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext(),
        UserByIdProfile.this);

image.setTag(image_url);

  // whenever you want to load an image from url
 // call DisplayImage function
 // url - image url to load
 // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
 // image - ImageView 
  imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, UserByIdProfile.this, image);
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322428/unable-to-set-image-view-background-image-using-universal-image-loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change in **load_full_image** method of **imageLoader** class, like below

```
public class ImageLoader {
 ...
Context mContext;
...

public ImageLoader(Context context, Activity acc) {
...
mContext = context
....

}


public void load_full_image(ImageView img, String _name, Bitmap btmp) {
img_path = new ArrayList<String>();

File[] file_array = cacheDir.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < file_array.length; i++) {
    img_path.add(file_array[i].getName());
}

if (img_path.contains(_name)) {
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/" + sd_card_folder_name + "/"
                                + _name));
     img.setBackground(d);
} else {

    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),btmp);
    img.setBackground(d);
}
}
}
```

try this code may be it will work

Comment: i have edited above code for that, check that and add that code in image loader class for context

Comment: if i change PhotoTOLoad intead of photoTOLoas giving Me Error
this
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field PhotoToLoad.imageView

Comment: you have to declare Context globaly in ImageLoader Class and set it in  the constructor of ImageLoader Class. after that you can use that context every where in Imageloader class

Comment: ok remove photoToLoad from your code and then check it. and let me know is it working or not ?

Comment: What To Remove ..PhotoTOLoad Class ..Or photoToload..if photoToLoad Is Me Error ..

Comment: only remove photoToLoad.imageView.setBackground(d); this line from load_full_image method.look i have edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a instance of ImageLoader but have not Initialize ImageLoader. For this add this line of code in your constructor after imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); :

imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(ctx));

You have not declared any option for your imageLoader. Modify your DisplayImageOptions code as below:

DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder() .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.image_loading) .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image) .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.image_failed) .cacheInMemory(true) .cacheOnDisc(true) .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) .build();

Answer (score -1):

```
[Use this project aims to provide a reusable instrument for asynchronous image loading, caching and displaying.][1]

Features

1)Multithread image loading (async or sync)
2)Wide customization of ImageLoader's configuration (thread executors, downloader, decoder, 3)memory and disk cache, display image options, etc.)
4)Many customization options for every display image call (stub images, caching switch, decoding options, Bitmap processing and displaying, etc.)
5)Image caching in memory and/or on disk (device's file system or SD card)
6)Listening loading process (including downloading progress)
*****Android 2.0+ support


  [1]: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
```